# unable to get, set selectedItem from the listbox containing radiobuttons being generated dynamically in wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Am trying to populate listbox with dynamic radiobuttons which are being customized to togglebuttons. I could populate listbox items with radiobuttons as said above. However, once we select any of the radiobuttons am unable to set the selected item from list of radiobuttons in my viewmodel object while debugging.

The following is the xaml code in my resource directory

```
 <Style x:Key="ScreensList" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2, 2, 2, 0" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <RadioButton
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Mode=TwoWay}">
                                    <RadioButton.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <ToggleButton  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                                    <StackPanel Width="80" Height="60" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,20,10">
                                                        <Image Source="Default.png" Height="40"></Image>
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ScreenNumber}" FontSize="11"></TextBlock>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </ToggleButton>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </RadioButton.Template>
                                </RadioButton>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

the below is my xaml code in xaml page

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ScreensList" ItemsSource="{Binding ScreenCollection}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ScreenManager}" 
                  Style="{StaticResource ScreensList}" Width="365">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

the following is the viewmodel.cs

```
   public ObservableCollection<ScreensManager> ScreenCollection { get; set; }



    private ScreensManager _screenManager;

    public ScreensManager ScreenManager
    {
        get { return _screenManager; }
        set
        {
            if (_screenManager != value)
            {
                if (_screenManager != null)
                {
                    _screenManager = value;


                }
            }
        }
    }

 private void AddScreens()
    {
        int screenCount = Screen.AllScreens.Length;

        if (ScreenCollection == null)
            ScreenCollection = new ObservableCollection<ScreensManager>();
        for (int screenCounter = 1; screenCounter <= screenCount; screenCounter++)
        {
           if (screenCounter == 1)
           { 
            _screenManager = new ScreensManager();
            _screenManager.ScreenNumber = screenCounter;
            ScreenCollection.Add(_screenManager);
           }
        }
    }
```

the following is the code in my ScreenManager.cs model class file

```
 public ScreensManager()
   {

   }

   private int _screenNumber;
   public int ScreenNumber
   {
       get { return _screenNumber; }
       set
       {
           _screenNumber = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("ScreenNumber");
       }
   }

   private bool _selectedScreen;
   public bool SelectedScreen
   {
       get { return _selectedScreen; }
       set
       {
           if (_selectedScreen = value)
           {
               _selectedScreen = value;
               if (_selectedScreen != value)
               {
                   OnPropertyChanged("SelectedScreen");

               }
           }
       }
   }


    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Am unable to find where I am actually going wrong as completely new to mvvm, someone please help me resolve my issue..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SelectedScreen` is of type `bool`, and should be of type `ScreensManager`

Your `ListBox.ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection<ScreensManager>`, meaning your `ListBox` contains a collection of `ScreensManager` objects, however your `SelectedItem` is of type `bool`. A bool object is never equal to a `ScreensManager` object, so WPF doesn't select anything since the `SelectedItem` is not found in the `ItemsSource`.

Change the `SelectedScreen` type to be `ScreensManager` instead of `bool`, and be sure it is equal to an item that exists in the `ScreenCollection`. WPF compares objects by reference, not value, so

```
ScreenManager.SelectedScreen = ScreenCollection.FirstOrDefault(); // Works
ScreenManager.SelectedScreen = new ScreensManager() { ... }; // Won't work
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just tried changing it as is specified by you above..However, Am confused in using the style attribute in the resources because I have a usercontrol that am using currently with a resource directory attribute as following :
<UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="..\default.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources> could you please let me know how to add that style as resource in my xaml.

Comment: @user1105705 You can use `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` inside your `<ListBox>` tags, and set the style from there instead

Comment: yeah that's great.thank you...but the result is again the same. Am unable to get set the ScreenManager.SelectedScreen property in my code. could you please help me resolve the thing.

Comment: @user1105705 Are you setting the `ScreenManager.SelectedScreen` to an item that exists in the `ScreenCollection` collection? WPF compares objects by reference, not value, so something like `ScreenManager.SelectedScreen = ScreenCollection.FirstOrDefault();` would work, but `ScreenManager.SelectedScreen = new ScreensManager() { ... };` will not. Also, does `SelectedScreen` raise a property change notification when it changes?

Comment: @user1105705 Actually nevermind, I just took another look at your code and see your problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have actually missed to show the IsSelected property in my code that I added now. if you see the viewmodel class, I have took a property of type bool to set the screenmanager.selectedscreen value and the same is being used in AddScreens() to populate the collection object. could you please tell me...why doesn't it seems to be working.

Comment: @user1105705 Your `ListBox` contains a collection of `ScreenManager` objects, while your `SelectedItem` property is bound to a boolean value, so your `SelectedItem` is never found in your `ItemsSource`. You need to change your `SelectedItem` property (`ScreenManager.SelectedScreen`) so be the same type as whatever the `ItemsSource` is, which in this case is a `ScreensManager` object.

Comment: oh....That's really Great...Thanks a lot..It's hitting the ScreenManager property..once selected.however..Am getting the ScreenManager as null..could you please let me know the way to get the selected value instead of null in that one..thanks again..

Comment: @user1105705 I'd need to see the code you're using if this is a different problem, but providing the `ScreenManager.SelectedScreen` is of the same type as whatever `ListBox.ItemsSource` is, then it should get updated anytime you change the selection. If that's not the case, perhaps open a new SO question with the relevant code.

Comment: That's Great Rachel, Thank you so much...I have modified my xaml and the viewmodel.cs code as well(my code has been updated as above) and my issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the binding is in two-way mode:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ScreenManager.SelectedScreen, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I have tried it but then it didnt work.